# Python 2.7 on MacOS : Matplotlib causing ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I'm running El Capitan MacOS 10.11.3
i have a problem with Matplotlib

the following snippet to import the Matplotlib,that I execute inside jupyter notebook in Chrome

```
#These are all the modules we'll be using later. Make sure you can import them
# before proceeding further.
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

gives the (long) error message

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-de762420594c> in <module>()
      2 # before proceeding further.
      3 from __future__ import print_function
----> 4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
   1129 
   1130 # this is the instance used by the matplotlib classes
-> 1131 rcParams = rc_params()
   1132 
   1133 if rcParams['examples.directory']:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in rc_params(fail_on_error)
    973         return ret
    974 
--> 975     return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
    976 
    977 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error, use_default_template)
   1098         parameters specified in the file. (Useful for updating dicts.)
   1099     """
-> 1100     config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
   1101 
   1102     if not use_default_template:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
   1016     cnt = 0
   1017     rc_temp = {}
-> 1018     with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
   1019         try:
   1020             for line in fd:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.pyc in __enter__(self)
     15     def __enter__(self):
     16         try:
---> 17             return self.gen.next()
     18         except StopIteration:
     19             raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield")

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in _open_file_or_url(fname)
    998     else:
    999         fname = os.path.expanduser(fname)
-> 1000         encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
   1001         if encoding is None:
   1002             encoding = "utf-8"

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.pyc in getdefaultlocale(envvars)
    541     else:
    542         localename = 'C'
--> 543     return _parse_localename(localename)
    544 
    545 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.pyc in _parse_localename(localename)
    473     elif code == 'C':
    474         return None, None
--> 475     raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
    476 
    477 def _build_localename(localetuple):

ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

if i type pip install matplotlib in the terminal,

```
 $ pip install matplotlib
```

looks like it worked fine

```
$ pip install matplotlib

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cycler in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing!=2.0.0,!=2.0.4,>=1.5.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from python-dateutil->matplotlib)
```

Whats wrong ???
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unknown locale error. Add these lines in your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Also run this command in the terminal to reload the file.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: thank you so much , you saved my day , you're a genius